ObservableCollection inside of an ObservableCollection, input new item in existing ObservableCollection
I have 2 classes Patent and Author in Model. Class Patent have observablecollection PatentAuthors which stores all authors of patent of which there may be several.
public class Patent
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Number {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Author> PatentAuthors {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public Patent()
    {

    }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FullName {get; set;}
    public string Adres {get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}

    public Author()
    {

    }
}

Also in Model i have a PatentManager class where i create an observablecollection of Patents and where i store all the patents and observablecollection of authors inside it.
public static ObservableCollection<Patent> _DataBasePatent = new()
{
    
}


public static ObservableCollection<Patent> GetPatents()
{
    return _DataBasePatent;
}

public static void AddPatent(Patent patent)
{
    _DataBasePatent.Add(patent);
}

In ViewModel i have class AddPatentViewModel which have command to add new patent and only 1 author of patent to observablecollection _DataBasePatent, that command binded to button.
public class AddPatentViewModel
{
    public ICommand AddPatentCommand {get;set;}
    public string AddNumber {get;set;}
    public string AddName {get;set;}
    public string AuthorFullName {get;set;}


    public AddPatentViewModel()
    {
        AddPatentCommand = new RelayCommand(AddPatent, canAddPatent);
    {

    public bool canAddPatent(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void AddPatent(object obj)
    {
        PatentManager.AddPatent(new()
            {
                Number = AddNumber, 
                Name = AddName,
                PatentAuthors = new ()
                    {
                        FullName = AuthorFullName
                    } 
            });
    }
}

So, my question is what if i want to add new Author to an existing patent? Also i have a Method SelectedPatent in ViewModelBase which return value of clicked patent in listview itemsource, it helps me to view all info of clicked patent.
I tried to write a new class AddAuthorToOldPatent with Command AddNewAuthorToOldPatentCommand
public class AddPatentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand AddNewAuthorToOldPatentCommand {get;set;}
    public string AuthorFullName {get;set;}


    public AddPatentViewModel()
    {
        AddNewAuthorToOldPatentCommand= new RelayCommand(AddNewAuthorToOldPatent, canAddNewAuthorToOldPatent);
    {

    public bool canAddNewAuthorToOldPatent(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void AddNewAuthorToOldPatent(object obj)
    {
        Patent patent = new Patent();
        var found = patent.FirstOrDefault(SelectedPatent);
        found.PatentAuthors.Add(new(){FullName = AuthorFullName});
        
    }
}

But it doesnt work. I'm new in c# and mvvm pattern.

The "patent" (in your scenario) comes before the "author"; so there is "no" add new author to new patent. You have only: Add new patent; Add new author to "old" patent. Beyond that, you might have: delete "old" author from "old" patent. Or, Remove patent and all authors.

@GerrySchmitz Did I understand correctly that it won't work to add a new author to the old patent? And it turns out that it is necessary to initially specify all authors when creating a patent?

I'm saying that attempting to add an "author and patent", at the same time, is what's confusing this scenario. Taking it in logical steps makes things clearer and easier to build and maintain. e.g. Can't add author without "adding" patent "first". Maybe the "author' is not known (at this time) and we just want to add patents. That why adding an "author and patent", at the same time, is an enhancement; and not a "requirement".

You probably want to create a PatentView and bind its DataContext to the SelectedPatent property. I.e.
<PatentView DataContext="{Binding SelectedPatent}"/>

You should probably also decide to either create a PatentViewModel and AuthorViewModel, or make your existing Patent & Author-classes implement INofityPropertyChanged. Using different model and view model classes is the recommended approach, but it does require some more code. The main point is that every class accessed by the views should implement INotifyPropertyChanged [*], otherwise changes will not propagate correctly to the UI.
You can then add the button to your PatentView, bound to the corresponding AddNewAuthorCommand on the PatentViewModel or Patent class.
[*] There might be some exceptions, but always implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or equivalent interface is the recommended practice.

Excuse me for asking a stupid question, but could you explain a little more specifically? Like what is PatentView from your answer? And i have INotifyPropertyChanged and i calling it after adding new author to old patent but then i save the data from _DataBasePatent to txt file where is no any new authors only those that were added during patent creation
